# Dynamic Template color change in bpm

Tags: javascript, css, business-process-management

I have created a template in BPM. I want to change the color of  the template dynamically depending upon some string value.
for example, 
if( tw.local.groupname=="FH" )
template color should be blue.
else if (tw.local.groupname=="IFH")
template color should be red.

If any of you have worked on this and have a solution, please help me out

Comment: use some javascript to update css background

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. Can you tell me how I can access the template and what function should I use to change the color?